# What is the type of the useState setter function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Sometimes the setter function of a `useState` hook must be passed around. What is the right way to type that function?

```ts
// some component with useState
const [infoText, setInfoText] = useState<string>(""); 

// same component calls a function in which the setter function is needed.
getInfoText(setInfoText);

// in the definition of that function (getInfoText) I now want to correctly type the setter function
export function getInfoText(setInfoText: ???) {
```

P.S.: I know that there are a couple of similar questions. I want to provide a general question without context such as: what is the correct type for this piece of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of the state setter in React is `Dispatch<SetStateAction<TypeOfTheState>>` where `Dispatch`, and `SetStateAction` can be imported from `"react"`. As an example:

```typescript
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState } from "react";

export default function Component() {
  // The type of setInfoText is Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>
  const [infoText, setInfoText] = useState<string>("");

  // We can give it as an argument to foo, as it's typed below
  foo(setInfoText);

  return <></>;
}

function foo(stateSetter: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>) {}
```